# Random number with specific variance in Python

Tags: python, random, variance

In a Python program, I need to generate normally-distributed random numbers with a specific, user-controlled variance. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import math
from random import gauss

my_mean = 0
my_variance = 10

random_numbers = [gauss(my_mean, math.sqrt(my_variance)) for i in range(100)]
```

This gets you 100 normally-distributed random numbers with mean 0 and variance 10.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`random.normalvariate`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.normalvariate) (or `random.gauss` if you don't need thread-safety), and set the `sigma` argument to the square root of the variance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sample from a specific range of numbers, you can do it like this:

```
mu = 350
variance = 10
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(1,572,572)
p = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)
random_number = np.random.choice(x, p=p/np.sum(p))
```

This way, we can also plot the distribution:

```
plt.plot(x, p)
plt.show()
```

[image]