# What is the difference between random.normalvariate() and random.gauss() in python?

Tags: python, random, gaussian, normal-distribution

What is the difference between [`random.normalvariate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.normalvariate) and [`random.gauss()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.gauss)?

They take the same parameters and return the same value, performing essentially the same function.

I understand from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815748/2642502) that [`random.gauss()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.gauss) is not [thread safe](https://www.quora.com/What-is-thread-safety-in-Python), but what does this mean in this context? Why should a programmer care about this? Alternatively posed, why was both a thread safe and non-thread safe version of included in Python's 'random'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thread-safe pieces of code must account for possible [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) during execution. This introduces overhead as a result of [synchronization schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) like mutexes, semaphores, etc.

However, if you are writing non-reentrant code, no race conditions normally arise, which essentially means that you can write code that executes a bit faster. I guess this is why `random.gauss()` was introduced, since the python doc says it's faster than the thread-safe version.

Answer (score 24):

This is an interesting question. In general, the best way to know the difference between two python implementations is to *inspect the code yourself*:

```
import inspect, random
str_gauss = inspect.getsource(random.gauss)
str_nv=inspect.getsource(random.normalvariate)
```

and then you print each of the strings to see how the sources differ. A quick look at the codes show that not only they behave differently multithread-wise, but also that the algorithms are not the same; for example, `normalvariate` uses something called the *Kinderman and Monahan* method, as per the following comments in `str_nv`:

```
# Uses Kinderman and Monahan method. Reference: Kinderman,
# A.J. and Monahan, J.F., "Computer generation of random
# variables using the ratio of uniform deviates", ACM Trans
# Math Software, 3, (1977), pp257-260.
```

Comment: It is sad that this kind of documentation cannot be found in the supposed documentation. Any insight why that may be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about this but the Python Documentation says that random.gauss is slightly faster so if you're OK with non-thread safe then you can go a little faster.

Answer (score -2):

In a multi-threaded system, calling `random.normalvariate` twice very quickly in succession will cause the internal code of `random.normalvariate` to be run twice, potentially before the first call has had a chance to return. Internal variables may of the function may not be reset before the second, which may cause errors in the function output.

Successive calls to `random.gauss` must instead wait for earlier calls to return before being called themselves.

The advantage with `random.normalvariate` is therefore that it is faster, but may produce an erroneous output.

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  Have you mixed up the thread safety of random.gauss and random.normalvariate?